# Redefining commands in a new environment

Tags: latex, tex

Two questions:

1. Does LaTeX allow one to (re)define commands within a `\newenvironment`? I've tried using `\renewcommand`, `\newcommand` and `\def` in the *before* declaration but to no avail.
2. How would one redefine `\item` when creating a new list environment?

I've created a new type of list environment from scratch using `\newenvironment` while using another token instead of `\item` for each  but I'd really like to keep things consistent by using `\list` and redefining `\item`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure; it's hard to know what went wrong without seeing your code. As an answer to your two questions, see if this helps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newenvironment{myitemize}{%
  \begin{list}{}{}% whatever you want the list to be
  \let\olditem\item
  \renewcommand\item{\olditem ITEM: }
}{%
  \end{list}
}  
\begin{myitemize}
\item one \item two
\end{myitemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried it and succeeded but my original problem concerns parameters. I've asked another question.

Answer (score 12):

Too late perhaps, but it may be useful for someone else

```
\newenvironment{coolitemize}{%
\let\olditem\item% 
\renewcommand\item[2][]{\olditem \textbf{##1}\\[0.3\baselineskip]##2}%
\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}%
}
```

and use it

```
\begin{coolitemize}
\item[Title of my first item] Text of my 1st item.
\item[Second one] And some text here.
\end{coolitemize}
```