# Redefining Commands with Parameters using \newenvironment

Tags: latex, tex

Pursuant to this question:

[Redefining Commands in a New Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486104/redefining-commands-in-a-new-environment)

How does one redefine (or define using `\def`) a macro that uses parameters?  I keep getting an `illegal parameter definition in \foo` error. Since I require custom delimiters, I can't use `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand`.

A general form of my code looks like this:

```
\newenvironment{foo}{% 
    ...spacing stuff and counter defs...
    \def\fooitem#1. #2\endfooitem{%
        ...stuff...
    }
    \def\endfooitem{endfoo}
}
{...after material (spacing)...}
```

This must be possible. Right now I'm using plain-TeX definitions (as I mentioned in the question above) but I'd really like to be consistent with the LaTeX system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double the # characters for every nested definition. Internally, a \newcommand or a \newenvironment is calling \def.

```
\newenvironment{foo}{% 
  ...
  \def\fooitem##1. ##2\endfooitem{%
    ...
```

Besides that, this is the way to do what you're trying to do; there is no pure-LaTeX method to define a macro with delimited arguments.